# Fixed point of limit equal to limit of fixed points?

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose $f\left(x,\alpha\right)$
  is a parameterized function.

$f:\,D\times\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow D$
  where $D$
  is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Suppose $x^{*}$
  is a fixed point of $f\left(x,1\right)$
 . That is, $f\left(x^{*},1\right)=x^{*}$.

Under what conditions is $x^{*}$
  also the limit of a the sequence of fixed points of $f\left(x,\alpha\right)$
  as $\alpha\rightarrow1$
 ?

Is continuity of $f$ sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One useful example:  $f(x,\alpha) = \alpha x$ (where $0 \in D$).  Every point of $D$ is a fixed point of $f(x,1)$, but $0$ is the only fixed point of $f(x,\alpha)$ for $\alpha \ne 1$.

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice simple couterexample.